# Python Plotly not showing 3d interactive plot

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, spyder

I am using `Spyder` ide. I have `plotly` 5.5.0 installed on my pc. The following executes with no errors but does not show/popup the 3d interactive plot.
Code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to interact with the figure running from Spyder you will need to call `show` with the `'browser'` renderer (this will show the figure on your default browser). The code provided with this change will look something like this:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
fig.show(renderer='browser')
```

Comment: Also I found the following solution somewhere online but yours is simple and good. `    import plotly.express as px
    from plotly.offline import plot
    import plotly
    fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x=xlbl, y=ylbl, z=zlbl,
                  color=wlbl,opacity=0,
                  color_discrete_sequence = plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)
    temp_name = 'Temp_plot.html'
    plot(fig, filename = temp_name, auto_open=False)    
    plot(fig)`

Comment: Presently your solution renders a default color scale. How can I set it to `viridis`.

Comment: Not sure about that but maybe a kwarg of `plotly.express.scatter_3d` could be useful. Maybe the `color_continuous_scale` or `color_discrete_sequence`:  https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter_3d.html

Comment: Yes! `color_continuous_scale = plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis` solved the problem. I was assigning to the wrong kwarg. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help!

Comment: If you don't mind, I have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70871976/python-plotly-scatter-3d-plot-colormap-customization

Comment: I appreciate for looing at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884594/plotly-scatter-3d-set-camera-reduce-white-space