# Python Plotly scatter 3D plot colormap customization

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly. I am getting the plot. The problem is, I am using seasons as colormap. I have used 1 for fall, 2 for winter, ..,4 for summer. Now, the colomap shows these numbers and also 1.5, 2.5 etc. I want to show Names instead of numbers

My code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x=xlbl, y=ylbl, z=zlbl,
              color=wlbl,opacity=0,
              color_continuous_scale  = plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)
temp_name = 'Temp_plot.html'
plot(fig, filename = temp_name, auto_open=False,
     image_width=1200,image_height=800)    
plot(fig)
```

Present output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [modify the coloraxis](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/) by adding the following lines to your code:

```
cat_labels = ["Fall", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer"]
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar=dict(ticktext=cat_labels, 
                                   tickvals=list(range(1, len(cat_labels)+1))))
```

Sample output with random data:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate for looing at my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884594/plotly-scatter-3d-set-camera-reduce-white-space