# Plotly scatter 3d set camera, reduce white space

Tags: python, plotly, interactive, scatter3d

I am plotting plotly scatter 3d in `spyder` IDE and it is working fine. Along with that, I am trying to save a particular camera view as png. This is where I am running issues into. This article (https://nbviewer.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/3d-camera-controls.ipynb) I found after a few hours of search is quite useful in let me know the right numbers for a view I am trying and addressed my main problem. The reason I am writing this post here to address the minor problems: reducing the white space

My code:

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x=xlbl, y=ylbl, z=zlbl,
              color=wlbl,opacity=0,
              color_continuous_scale  = plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)
cat_labels = ["Fall", "Winter", "Spring", "Summer"]
fig.update_coloraxes(colorbar=dict(ticktext=cat_labels, 
                               tickvals=list(range(1, len(cat_labels)+1))))
fig.update_layout(font=dict(size=12))
fig.update_layout(
    width=400, height=400,
    margin=dict(t=0, r=0, l=0, b=0
))

name = 'eye = (x:0., y:2.5, z:0.)'
camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
    center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
    eye=dict(x=2, y=0.1, z=0.1)
)
fig.update_layout(scene_camera=camera, 
                    # title=name
                  )
# save the present camera as a png file
fig.write_image("fig_name.png", scale=5,width=1)
# Render and save HTML interactive 3d plot
temp_name = 'Temp_plot.html'
plot(fig, filename = file_loc+'python_plots_manju//'+temp_name, auto_open=False,
      image_width=1200,image_height=800
     )
plot(fig)
```

Present PNG outputs:

[image]
[image]

Expected output:

1. How to drop the white space in the above plots?
2. How to control the gap between ticks and labels?
3. In the above plot, I want to keep the same zoom position but slight rotation along y-axis? How to do it?